# Does apple and google requires me to buy code signing certificate?

Tags: android, ios, publish

Seriously, i have search as many as i can and can't answer this.

It's way confusing when you visit plenty of certificate issuers sites and nobody truly says that google and apple REQUIRES me or NOT to BUY these expensive code signing certificates.

*It maybe not a question for stackoverflow but i haven't found something related to it in the other forums but here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the platforms Android and iOS you need an code signing certificate. But a regular code signing certificate offered by a lot of commercial CA are not necessary (Android) or can't be used at all (iOS).

For Android you can just [generate a self-signed certificate](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) (uploading it to Google is optional). Just make sure to backup this certificate and private key as it is required for updating your app in PlayStore. For app publishing via Google PlayStore a [Google Developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en) is required ($25 USD one-time registration fee).

For iOS you need an Apple ID account and register for the [Apple Developer account](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) which costs you $99 USD per year (for certain persons/groups you can get it for [free](https://developer.apple.com/support/membership-fee-waiver/)).

Comment: thanks! so all i really need to pay is the register fee (google) and "anual membership" (apple)? So the paid certificates only matters for windows and PC softwares/drivers i guess?

Comment: @LucasBarroca For Android you only need to pay if you want to publish apps via PlayStore. For Apple you have to pay AFAIK even if you just want to develop apps for yourself that run on a real device.

Comment: I already know that apple requires XCode and Mac and etc for compiling, i was just confused about the apps stores publishing and these expensive code signing certificates around the internet... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning mobile app development and you want to write few sample projects then you can run them on simulators/emulators. This does not require any certificates. But if you want to run them on actual device/submit to Appstore/Play Store you need certificates and profiles.

Hope I answered your question :)

Comment: as i've learned here, these certificates are provided by google and apple, don't requiring me to buy one, sure? that's why it's confusing lol

Comment: All you need to have is a Developer account, with that you will be able to create certificates. This link gives you further details: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

YES these certificates are provided by Apple and Google, need to pay for membership(based on membership type). No need to pay specifically for Certificates.